# I'm trying to make my triangles redraw themselves when I click the mouse, but they only just multiply when I mouse click

Tags: java, processing

When I run this program the green triangles appear all over the place when I click instead I want it to reposition itself to a random place and remove the original green triangle

```
float x;

void setup()
{
  size (800, 600);
  background(29, 154, 178);
  x=random(width);
    frameRate(30);
}

void draw()
{
  noStroke();

  fill(91, 180, 118 );
  triangle(x, 20, 0, height, width, height);

  fill(82, 45, 80);
  triangle(width/2-200, 120, 0, height, width, height);

  fill(82, 45, 60);
  triangle(width/2+150, 220, 0, height, width, height);

  fill(82, 45, 28);
  triangle(width/2-100, 320, 0, height, width, height);
  fill(243, 245, 158);
  rect(0, 525, 800, 100);
  
  if(mousePressed == true)
  {
    x=random(width);
  }
}
```

Comment: This kinda looks like a homework problem.  Show me where you are drawing the triangle and then show me where you think the triangle is being removed.

Answer (score 1):

Then add `noLoop()` in your setup so you're not drawing the same thing 60 times a second, and use [mouse click handling](https://processing.org/reference/mouseClicked_.html) instead, with a [redraw](https://processing.org/reference/redraw_.html) call so you only draw when there is something new to draw:

```
float x, y, triangleSideLength;

void setup() {
  size(300,300);
  noLoop();
  triangleSideLength = 30; // or whatever value it needs to be of course
}

void draw() {
  x = random(0, width - triangleSideLength);
  y = random(0, height - triangleSideLength);
  drawTriangleAt(x, y);
}

void drawTriangleAt(float x, float y) { 
  //...triangle drawing code here...
}

void mouseClicked() {
  redraw();
}
```

Also note that you usually want to constrain your x/y coordinates so that a triangle will always "fit on the screen" instead of getting an x/y coordinate that happens to have x=width and now your triangle is basically 100% out of view.

Comment: Thanks for the help as it only places one triangle when I click, but how do I get the triangle to disappear after I click as when I click right now the previous ones stay on screen

Comment: That's something you weren't asking about in your question, so I can certainly explain how to do that, but you'll have to update your post first to [make it clear](/help/how-to-ask) both what you already have, and what you "need" to have happen instead. There is no "fading things out" without either using persistent animation looping, or tracking positions in a list of coordinates.